# How to get each new survey to start from 1?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Please bear with my rambling for a moment.

I have a table called `Survey`.

This table is used to store Different kinds of surveys.

For instance, there is `Employee` Survey.

`Salary` Survey, etc.

Then there is a `Questions` table.

This table houses questions related to each Survey.

It has surveyId fk to Survey table.

But the real kicker is that it also has a field called QuestionOrder.

I need this field to be able to order and re-order questions related to a particular Survey.

For instance, right now, if a user takes an Employee survey, the first question starts with number 1), the next question, 2), et.

If we start with a new Survey, we would like the question for that survey to start with 1.

I would like to do this with QuestionOrder field.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this can be easily done via SQL. Perhaps you should move this logic to the application layer. For instance, when you add a new question, the `QuestionOrder` will be equal to `"# of QuestionOrder in Survey" + 1`

Comment: Fantastic idea.

Only problem though is we start have a problem of starting a new survey with a new question starting from number 1.

Remember that there is a Survey table and it has SurveyID integer, Title, and Description.

If I have 2 surveys on this table, then there is surveyId 1 and surveyId 2.

So, your proposal doesn't solve the problem of starting a new question with a new number 1 unless I misunderstand you but really great idea.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Create view with ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY surveyId ORDER BY >as you need<) as QuestionOrder

Comment: I was able to resolve this using stored procedure but the idea is borrowed from @acardenas89.

So, thanks a lot all.